# Google Calendar API batch request - Failed to get multipart boundary

Tags: google-calendar-api, multipartform-data

I'm trying to do a batch call to get Calendars from Google.
I've tried following several answers here on StackOverflow:

- [What is the endpoint to make batch request for Google Calendar v3 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23398782/what-is-the-endpoint-to-make-batch-request-for-google-calendar-v3-api)
- [Batch request in Google Calendar V3 REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425934/batch-request-in-google-calendar-v3-rest-api)

and also followed the Google Documentation:

- https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/batch#format-of-a-batch-request

Since the general endpoint (https://www.googleapis.com/batch) is deprecated, I'm using `https://www.googleapis.com/batch/calendar/v3` to post to.

I'm posting a plain text body:

```
POST /batch/calendar/v3 HTTP/1.1

Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="batch_foobarbaz"

--batch_foobarbaz
Content-Type: application/http

GET /calendar/v3/calendars/*calendarId1*

--batch_foobarbaz
Content-Type: application/http

GET /calendar/v3/calendars/*calendarId2*

--batch_foobarbaz--
```

The result I keep getting is:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Failed to get multipart boundary.",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the boundary in the Google example `boundary="batch_foobarbaz"` or are you using the one for calendar `boundary=batch_google_calendar`?

Comment: Could you provide more details as to where you are testing this and the programming language used if any? that way the community can help you by testing this if needed. See [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Also,are you using `--batch_foobarbaz` on your implementation or the correct one `--batch_google_calendar`?

Comment: @GiselleValladares I couldn't find this in the docs, but even when using it, it doesn't change the error.

Comment: @YancyGodoy no language used, just a simple POST request in Postman